# Constructor and methods cannot be applied

Tags: java

Working on this code and no idea why all the time I get error 
"constructor Book in class ... cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.lang.String,
found: no arguments,
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length:". 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Book {

private String title;

    public Book(String title) {
       this.title = title;

    }



    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? It looks like it's probably an error in how you're using this code.

Comment: As well as the error with trace, please show us *all* of your code

Comment: @Carcigenicate "constructor Book in class ... cannot be applied to given types;
required: java.lang.String,
found: no arguments,
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length:

Comment: That means you have `Book()` written somewhere. The constructor expects a String to act as the title of the book. When you post here, please include all relevant information, like the full error and a [mcve] of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not declare an instance of `Book` like this:

```
Book book = new Book();
```

since you do not have a constructor for it. So far you only have a constructor that accepts a String argument within a string parameter:

```
Book book = new Book("My Book Title");
```

If you want to also utilize an empty constructor so that the `setTitle()` setter method must be used to set a Title then add it to your class:

```
class Book {
    private String title;

    // Empty Constructor
    public Book() {

    }

    // Overloaded Constructor which accepts a
    // Title string argument.
    public Book(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

You could also just modify your existing constructor to be like this:

```
public Book(String... optionalTitle) {
    if (optionalTitle.length > 0) {
        this.title = optionalTitle[0];
    }
}
```

This constructor allows you to *optionally* supply a title argument. This way you can do your declarations either way (or add more than one title if you like with a few more changes).